# Why does the following code compile?

Tags: java, android

I was wondering why this code snippet compiles and runs

```
private BusRoute readRouteCursor( final Cursor c )
{
    final BusRoute result;
    final int count;
    if ( c == null || ( count = c.getCount() ) < 1 )
    {
        result = null;
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * Reads cursor
         */
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have it working just fine but when I stopped to think about it I wondered why, as the variable `count` is `final` but it's possible for it not to be set if the first condition of the `if` clause is met.

Does it work because the compiler is clever enough to see there are no uses of `count` from that point on, and it needn't be initialised at all?

Comment: A final variable can only be initialized once, so from what you have shown us the code is just fine.

Comment: There is only one initialization of result, here

Comment: Thanks for clearing that one up guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've answered this question yourself already! As there is no reference to the `count` variable apart from the conditional initialization, no compile error is reported. The error will only appear when you try to reference the variable further in the method body.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. A final variable does not need to be initialized in the declaration step. It is also called a "blank final".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this would fail only if `count` variable was a object's or class's field.

Why ?  Because default value is assigned by default for field. Thus, your statement:

`count = c.getCount()`

would effectively fail since it would represent a second assignment...

However, for local variable, default value is not assigned while the declaration is made.

So your code is perfectly valid because your `count` variable is never valued more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly valid scenario because you are initializing the variable `count` for the first time. Just try writing :

```
final int count = 0;
```

You'll get a compilation error